# change name of native shared library AAR and binary in android studio

Tags: android

I'm building a shared library AAR in Anroid Studio (3.4.2)

the name of the build is `app-debug_-debug.aar` - the project is called `app` - how do I change the name of the project to `foobar` so that my library will be called `foobar-debug_-debug.aar`

also the binary of library.so file with the is called `libjni_lib.so` and i'd like to rename that to `libbarbaz.so` too

how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change ethe binary name I had to do 2 things

1) change the `BINARY_NAME` in the `CMakeLists.txt` file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

SET(BINARY_NAME "my_new_binary_name")
```

this is then used in a couple of places

```
add_library( ${BINARY_NAME}

...

target_link_libraries( ${BINARY_NAME}
```

2) change the `System.loadLibrary` to call my new binary name

```
public class Java
{
    static
    {
        System.loadLibrary ("my_new_binary_name");
    }

    public native static void initialiseMyAPP (Context appContext);
}
```

And to change the library name, I renamed the file when I was copying it is a host destination

```
    rename { String fileName ->
        fileName.replace("old_library_name.aar", "new_library_name.aar")
    }
``
```